# Oracle: Split data from one column into two columns based on data

Tags: oracle, calculated-columns

I have a strange situation.
a) I have to create a table B from Table A plus some custom columns. For example.
Table B should have few columns of table A and some additional columns(These are static values like NULL,static string and system timestmaps).

b) One column in Table A needs to be split into Two columns in Table B
example: Data  in Column X is [A1234, B5678, 0000, 1111]
Table B should have two columns AlphaColumn[A1234, B5678], NumberishColumn[0000, 1111]
The difference is : First letter of the data can be alphabet. Thats the only distinguishing criteria
[image]
How can I do this in one query?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `CASE` expression and simple string functions:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_b(firstname, lastname, alphacolumn, numberishcolumn)
SELECT firstname,
       lastname,
       CASE
       WHEN SUBSTR(employeeid, 1, 1) BETWEEN '0' AND '9'
       THEN NULL
       ELSE employeeid
       END,
       CASE
       WHEN SUBSTR(employeeid, 1, 1) BETWEEN '0' AND '9'
       THEN employeeid
       ELSE NULL
       END
FROM   table_a;
```

Or, you could create `table_b` as a `VIEW` instead of another table.